# How to Position Text Above a Horizontal Rule?

Tags: html, css

I want to position text above a rule and to the right of a heading, as shown at the bottom of the below image.

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
  <hr>
```

(I currently have no CSS for the 'character' class, since I've got nothing working.)

I've tried aligning the text, using CSS to float or position and the closest I've gotten is getting the in line with the rule, but it cuts it off at the end.

Can anyone offer some assistance?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/8zaccx77/

Comment: this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032850/html-css-how-to-put-text-both-right-and-left-aligned-in-a-paragraph

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.flex-container span.category {
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <span class="category">Characters</span>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `floating` in order to achieve that like first item will be `float: left;` and second item will be `float: right;`  an other solution will be `display: inline-block;` and you can also use `display:flex;`

```css
.float{overflow: hidden;}
.float h2{
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
.float .category{float: right;}


.inineblock{
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
}
.inineblock h2{
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.inineblock .category{
  width: 50%;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: right;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.flexbox{
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox h2{
  margin: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.flexbox .category{align-self: flex-end;}
```

```html
<div class="float">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="inineblock">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="flexbox">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
</div>
<hr>
```

```css
.float{overflow: hidden;}
.float h2{
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
.float .category{float: right;}


.inineblock{
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
}
.inineblock h2{
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.inineblock .category{
  width: 50%;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: right;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.flexbox{
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox h2{
  margin: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.flexbox .category{align-self: flex-end;}
```

```html
<div class="float">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="inineblock">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="flexbox">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="category"><em>Characters</em></div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how your code solves the question. This will help the OP understand your code as well as help future searchers

Answer (score 0):

use can also use this

```
.category
{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px; 
}
h2
{
         position:absolute
         left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how your code solves the question. This will help the OP understand your code as well as help future searchers.