# CSS align text to the right but align left on line break

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a text to the right but when the text is to long, it should make a line break and align it to the left of the text. It's hard for me to explain, that's why I have an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

As you can see, the text is aligned to the right of this small div. But when a line break occurs, it is logically also aligned to the right.

I tried to wrap it in a div, where the parent is aligned to the right and the child with the text to the left. The thing is I get a result like this:

[image]

which is still wrong, since the text isn't aligned to the right then, when it breaks. Is there a way to do that?
And I don't wanna have a max width or something for the text, since if there is enough space, it should take the whole width that is available for a line.

```css
body {
    background: #cccccc;
}

.parentDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.alignRight {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.alignLeft {
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="alignRight">
    <div class="alignLeft">
      bla
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alignRight">
    <div class="alignLeft">
      testing cool text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your Bit of code

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8wjv6mk/

Comment: try giving text-align: justify; to .alignLeft

Comment: @SuprajaGanji this way in my example the 'testing' would be on the left and 'cool' on the right. :/

Answer (score 0):

First Answer:

```css
p.para{
text-indent: 30px;
padding-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  Hello this is my text. This story is awesome. hello this is my text. This story is awesome. Hello this is my text. This story is awesome. Hello this is my text. This story is awesome. Hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome
</p>
```

Edit:

Or break your text like this..where you can play with first line and rest para anyhow you like.

```css
div.para>p:first-child{
 text-align:right;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
div.para>p:last-child{
 margin-top:0px;
  text-align:left;
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="para">
    <p>This is first line</p>
    <p>
        Rest of Lines... this is my text. This story is awesome. hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This
        story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome.hello this is my text. This story is awesome
    </p>
</div>
```

Even if this is not your intention then look at

[HTML/CSS: how to put text both right and left aligned in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032850/html-css-how-to-put-text-both-right-and-left-aligned-in-a-paragraph)

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is, I want the next line to start exactly where the first line starts, like where I draw the red line in the first image.

Comment: just added `padding-left:15px` this is what you want?

Comment: Sadly no. Your text won't align to the right, it only makes a padding to the left. So in case the text is smaller than the available width, it will not align to the right.

Comment: look at the new answer

Comment: No, that's still not what I want. Also the suggested link to the other question isn't what I want. But thank you for trying to help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need padding.

```css
body {
    background: #cccccc;
}

.parentDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.alignRight {
  padding-right:50px;
  padding-left:50px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.alignLeft {
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="alignRight">
    <div class="alignLeft">
      bla
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alignRight">
    <div class="alignLeft">
      testing cool text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that helps! This is a very, very, very late answer.

Tip: Use the padding to help you get what you want.